# after upgrade to .net core 2.2, inserts via EF were failing with error

Tags: exception, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

This code has been working fine prior to the upgrade to core 2.2
I can not understand what the **parameter name: key** is. I have also taken the code generated via the SQL profiler and run it directly in sql management studio and the code executes without any error

This error is generated on the `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Aslo note that when i downgraded the app back to .net core 2.1 again it worked without any issues

Exception generated is

```
  An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'RtasWebApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.FindIdentityMap(IKey key)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetDependents(InternalEntityEntry principalEntry, IForeignKey foreignKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.KeyPropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, IReadOnlyList`1 containingPrincipalKeys, IReadOnlyList`1 containingForeignKeys, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.KeyPropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, IReadOnlyList`1 keys, IReadOnlyList`1 foreignKeys, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectKeyChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase propertyBase, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase property, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetProperty(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ColumnModification.set_Value(Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommand.PropagateResults(ValueBuffer valueBuffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithPropagationAsync(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.FindIdentityMap(IKey key)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetDependents(InternalEntityEntry principalEntry, IForeignKey foreignKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.KeyPropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, IReadOnlyList`1 containingPrincipalKeys, IReadOnlyList`1 containingForeignKeys, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.KeyPropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property, IReadOnlyList`1 keys, IReadOnlyList`1 foreignKeys, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectKeyChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase propertyBase, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase property, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetProperty(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetCurrentValue(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ColumnModification.set_Value(Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommand.PropagateResults(ValueBuffer valueBuffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithPropagationAsync(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

**Any ideas greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 1):

That was a bug in `.net core 2.2.2` (see [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14226#issuecomment-471984559)). In my case, I installed `.net core 2.2.3` and the issue was solved. You can download it from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and created this on their GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14419

The issue for me was that I was using `services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>` in my Startup.cs.  Looks like there might be a bug when using the Connection Pool version EF.  Try reverting to the plain version of DbContext by removing the word Pool (`services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>`) and see if your issue goes away

Comment: Except I am already using the standard AddDbContext, so it isn't that. Cheers for the input though

Comment: Someone had a workaround for their issue that was giving a similar error message here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14226

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue trying to update lot of records at the same time and call SaveChanges(). This might happen when the update query takes more time to update the records there might be a timeout. You can update the CommandTimeout as a solution. In your data context class Add this to the constructor.

Database.SetCommandTimeout(10000);

So your code will look something like this.

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options, UserContext userContext)
{
    _userContext = userContext;
    _tenantDbInfo = tenantDbInfo;
    Database.SetCommandTimeout(10000);
}
```